# How to properly apply KO binding the following example

Tags: javascript, html, css, data-binding, knockout.js

Basicaly, I have viewModel in KO having array of 2 values, I need to change css class prop of element (`main`) when `<a>` elemets are being clicked (when 1st `li>a "Val1"` clicked, `<main class="stl1">...` and so on). Strangely , nothing happends to `<main>`:

```
<script>
        var mainViewModel = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.classArr = ['stl1', 'stl2'];
            self.cssUsed = ko.observable(0);

            self.getClass = function ( data, event ) {
                var dat = event.target.value;
                self.cssUsed = self.classArr[dat];
                console.log( dat + ' : ' + self.cssUsed );
            }

        }
        ko.applyBindings( new mainViewModel() );
</script>    

<div class='page'>
    <header>
       <nav>
         <ul >
           <li><a href="#" data-bind="value: 0, click: getClass">Val1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" data-bind="value: 1, click: getClass">Val2</a></li>
         </ul>

      </nav>
   </header>

  <div id='maincontent'>
          <main data-bind="css: cssUsed" >
              <div class="center"></div>
          </main>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it almost right. The problem was that your were assigning the value in the wrong way. Instead of

```
self.cssUsed = self.classArr[dat];
```

try

```
self.cssUsed(self.classArr[dat]);
```

Check it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6kzg6mnx/2/)